# RTP Server Simple implementation in C

Tags: c, rtp

I have researched about RTP Protocol, and just understand under theory how this protocol works. I want to have source code to see details how they really are.

For example : how server can send message ? how client can receive message ?

I have google, but all links reference me to RTP lib (it's too big for me to read it). Please tell me, just a simple code in C, how to use this protocol (in case of send/receive message), not to send/receive media files, synchronize them ...

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "C" standard for RTP.
The particular code is only as good as the programmers who wrote it and
commented/documented it. I'm not aware of an example for which give you intro to RTP

But somewhere is hope,you will find some related information like [live555](http://live555.com/) is useful  libraries and code examples of how to stream stuff from your own app

Also some RTP code [here](http://doxygen.asterisk.org/asterisk1.0/rtp_8c-source.html) i don't know how it works but you researched about RTP Protocol,so might be you get batter idea.

Comment: thanks :) I'm researching `live555`. it after compiles, work well. and it's a big library for me to learn. :D